# Hide toolbar in VirtualBox 5 fullscreen

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running VirtualBox 5.0 on Windows 7 in fullscreen mode. There is a toolbar sitting at the bottom of the guest's screen that opens when I hit it with the mouse. Is there any way to completely hide this toolbar so that it's completely gone?

It seems that in previous versions of VirtualBox, there was a checkbox in Settings -> General -> Advanced tab. However, there are options like this in in the Advanced tab anymore and parts of the options there seem to be integrated into the menu. I can't find the option to hide the toolbar in fullscreen. Is it still there?

Answer (score 3):

The option is now in Settings -> User Interface and is only available when the machine is powered off.